# How to disable [abc] suggestion on vs-code?

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code

I want to disable the [abc] suggestion on the vs-code editor I tried some solution but it doesn't work.
*Help me to disable it.*

[image: Image here]

```
Solution tried
```

> "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,

Comment: That should do it - try a reload?

Comment: That works for me even without reload.

Answer (score 60):

I believe the setting you're looking for is:

```
"editor.suggest.showWords": false
```

If you prefer the UI, you can also find it by doing the following

1. Navigate the menus: click on - `File > Preferences > Settings` (or press `Ctrl` + `,`)
2. Type `Show Words` in the search box at the top
3. Uncheck the setting `Editor > Suggest: Show Words`

You can find a full list of intellisense settings explained here
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

And the list of completions can be found here
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions

That little text suggestion was very annoying. This is what worked for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 15):

**oh yes I did it!**

```
"javascript.suggest.names": false
```

Comment: Chawki's suggestion wasn't working for me but this one did. Thanks sir!

Comment: God bless this line. Hahaha. Thanks!

Comment: How do you do it for Visual Studio Pro?

Answer (score 15):

After doing all the things suggested here, I still see *abc* suggestions for **all** the entries in my snippet file, not just the ones appropriate to the language I am using.
I did manage to make that acceptable, by setting the value of Settings > Editor > SnippetSuggestions to **top** ( `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"`). Like that at least the proper snippets are on top, making it easier to ignore the rest.

[image: suggestions apply / don't apply]

Comment: Much better than disabling abc, works like a charm!

Comment: nice answer! before, snippets used to be on top all the time.

Answer (score 7):

For me what worked was:

```
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
```

Answer (score 3):

- open settings: `cmd` + `,`
- change `Snippet Suggestions` to `top`
- and I recommend you change `Insert Mode` to `replace` too

[image]