# How to display the "abc" suggestions on my VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Normally, VS Code displays `abc` suggestions like the one below in the editor:

[image: VS Code abc]

However, the VS Code extension that I have created does not display these word suggestions for my files, which have a different different file extension (e.g. `myFile.mf`). In the `.vscode` directory of my extension, I opened `settings.json`, and added the line below:

```
{
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true
}
```

This change was not successful, so I tried doing what was suggested in the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827043/how-to-disable-abc-suggestion-on-vs-code) Stack Overflow question, but to no avail. I have also tried closing and reopening VS Code after making the changes, but the `abc` suggestions still won't appear. What should I do?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67279173/15247754). Maybe this helps.